# Unable to append unicode characters to text file using sp_OAMethod 'OpenTextFile' method in SQL Server (2008 R2)

Tags: sql-server, unicode, sql-server-2008-r2, file-writing

Here is the SQL Server stored procedure script I use to write text files

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AppendToFileSP] 
    (
     @FileName varchar(4000)
     , @Text1 NVARCHAR(MAX) 
     ) 
AS  
    DECLARE @FS int, @OLEResult int, @FileID int  

    EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FS OUT  
    --Open a file  
    Print @OLEResult

    EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FS, 'OpenTextFile', @FileID OUT, @FileName, 8 , 1 
    Print @OLEResult

    --Write Text1  
    EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FileID, 'WriteLine', NULL, @Text1  

    Print @OLEResult
    EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FileID  

    Print @OLEResult
    EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FS  

    Print @OLEResult
GO
```

Here is the sample query that I executed to replicate issue

```
DECLARE @Text1 NVARCHAR(MAX)  
SET @Text1 = N'共發現'
EXEC AppendToFileSP 'C:\AppTextFile1.txt',@Text1

Print '------------------'

SET @Text1 = N'sample'
EXEC AppendToFileSP 'C:\AppTextFile2.txt',@Text1
```

And the output I got is as below

```
0
0
-2146828283
0
0
------------------
0
0
0
0
0
```

Though files got created in both cases , it failed to write Chinese characters to the file(AppTextFile1.txt).

After I modified below piece of code from stored procedure

```
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FS, 'OpenTextFile', @FileID OUT, @FileName, 8 , 1
```

to

```
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FS, 'CreateTextFile', @FileID OUT, @FileName, 8 , 1
```

Both files got created. However it does not meet my need , I should be able to create a file and append unicode text to it.